# How to create the "Binding" class in that code?

Tags: c#, class, silverlight, data-binding, datagrid

I need to bind an `EntityCollection` to my `data-grid`, I found a solution [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/silverlight/en-US/9de0b70f-5196-4cd0-88ed-df34ec98bfd6/datagrid-itemssource-bound-to-entitycollectiont):

```
Binding binding = new Binding();
binding.Source = colecao;
binding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
dataGrid1.SetBinding(DataGrid.ItemsSourceProperty, binding);
```

However I'm not sure what the `Binding class` is and what library I need to import to create it.

Comment: It comes with presentationframework.dll. look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding(v=vs.110).aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As per MSDN Binding Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding(v=vs.110).aspx)

Binding Class provides high-level access to the definition of a binding, which connects the properties of binding target objects (typically, WPF elements), and any data source (for example, a database, an XML file, or any object that contains data).

> **Namespace:**  System.Windows.Data 
>   **Assembly:**  PresentationFramework (in PresentationFramework.dll)

[Here's one good example of it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752300(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @EugenePodskal Please read last line in OP's question. MSDN has answer for it

Comment: MSDN has many answers, but it is a good idea to post all the relevant information here - answer shall be as self-contained as possible. References are just a useful addition. Now it looks much better, but I'd still added some note that PresentationFramework.dll is added by default in Silverlight projects, and that OP just needs the appropriate using statement.

Comment: @EugenePodskal Thank you for suggestion. I'll take care of it